# Recursively parse string with markdown-like markup language

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a string of type:

```
'??__HELLO__?? WORLD ##SAMPLE --MAIN--##'
```

And I need to parse it and get array that contains:

```
[{ marker: '??', value: { marker: '__', value: 'HELLO' }, ' WORLD ', { marker: '##', value: ['SAMPLE ' , { marker: '--', value: 'MAIN' }]]
```

So I have this arkers:

```
this.markers = {
        b: '??',
        i: '##',
        u: '__',
        s: '--',
    };
```

And I have a function that generates stack:

```
parse(string) {
    this.string = string;
    this.stack = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        for (let marker of Object.values(this.markers)) {
            if (string[i] + string[i + 1] === marker) {
                this.stack.push({ marker: marker, index: i });
                this.stack.push('');
                i++;
                break;
            } else if (marker === Object.values(this.markers)[Object.values(this.markers).length - 1]) {
                this.stack[this.stack.length - 1] = this.stack[this.stack.length - 1].concat(string[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.stack.length; i++) {
        if (this.stack[i] === '') {
            this.stack.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    console.log(this.stack);
    return this.parseRecursively(this.stack[0]);
}
```

In my example stack will contain:

```
[ { marker: '??', index: 0 },
{ marker: '__', index: 2 },
'HELLO',
{ marker: '__', index: 9 },
{ marker: '??', index: 11 },
' WORLD ',
{ marker: '##', index: 20 },
'SAMPLE ',
{ marker: '--', index: 26 },
'MAIN',
{ marker: '--', index: 31 },
{ marker: '##', index: 33 } ]
```

And this function calls another one that recursively will generate the output array:

```
parseRecursively(element) {
    if (this.stack.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    let parsed = [];

    for (let i = this.stack.indexOf(element); i < this.stack.length; i++) {
        if (typeof this.stack[i] === 'object') {
            if (this.stack[i].marker === this.stack[this.stack.indexOf(this.stack[i]) + 1].marker) {
                let popped = this.stack.splice(this.stack.indexOf(this.stack[i]) + 1, 1)[0];
                let popped2 = this.stack.splice(this.stack.indexOf(this.stack[i]), 1)[0];

                return { marker: popped.marker, value: this.string.substring(popped2.index + 2, popped.index) };
            } else {
                parsed.push({ marker: this.stack[i].marker, value: this.parseRecursively(this.stack[this.stack.indexOf(this.stack[i]) + 1]) });
                i = -1;
            }
        } else {
            parsed.push(this.stack.splice(this.stack.indexOf(this.stack[i]), 1)[0]);
            i -= 2;
        }
    }
```

I tried many implementations of the above function but it still fails to parse the string.

So how can I rewrite this function so it would work?

Thanks!

P.S. Only plain JavaScript, nothing more and I think using regular expressions will help solve it easier, here's mine regex:

```
this.regex = /(\?{2}|#{2}|\-{2}|_{2})(.+?)(\1)/g;
```

Comment: Are there any obvious separators, or are all the groups enclosed? (e.g. `## Something\n` vs `## Something ##`)?

Comment: They are all enclosed, like tags, e.g. ??Hello??, not separators

Comment: Given the following; `function parse(str) {
    const regex = /(\?\?|__|##|--)(.*?)(\1)/;
    return regex.test(str) ? str.split(regex).filter(_ => _).map(parse).reduce((c, v) => c.concat(v), []) : str;
}` would that be a start?

Comment: Ok, so what's next?

Comment: Give me about 1 min, to post the followup :D

Comment: Ok, the thing you posted is a good clean version of creating the stack

Comment: Okay, maybe 5 mins :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a bit of thought, here is my take on your problem:

```js
function parse(str, markers = ['??', '__', '##', '--']) {
  // Escape the markers (mostly useless...)
  const e = markers.map(m => m.replace(/./g, '\\$&'))

  // Create regexs to match each individual marker.
  const groups = e.map(m => new RegExp('(' + m + ')(.*?)' + m));

  // Create the regex to match any group.
  const regex = new RegExp('(' + e.map(m => m + '.*?' + m).join('|') + ')');
  const output = [];

  // 'Match' the groups markers.
  str = str.split(regex).filter(_ => _);

  // Iterate over each of the split markers. e.g.
  // From: '??__HELLO__?? WORLD ##SAMPLE --MAIN--##'
  //   To: ['??__HELLO__??', ' WORLD ', '##SAMPLE --MAIN--##']
  return str.map(match => {
    // Find the marker if it is a marker.
    marker = groups.find(m => m.test(match));

    // If it's not a marker return the value.
    if (!marker) {
      return match.trim();
    }

    // It is a marker so make the marker object.
    match = match.match(marker);
    return {
      marker: match[1],
      // Do the recursion.
      value: parse(match[2], markers)
    }
  })
}

// Usage example:
console.log(
  parse('??__HELLO__?? WORLD ##SAMPLE --MAIN--##')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%;}
```

The individual regexes used in this code are build in the following style:

1. Escape every character; `??` becomes `\?\?`
2. The markers are isolated; `\?\?` becomes `(\?\?)`
3. The contents are matched using the following regex; `(.*?)`
4. The content is then surrounded by the markers; `(\?\?)(.*?)\?\?`

This means the default regex array looks like this:

```
[
  /(\?\?)(.*?)\?\?/,
  /(\_\_)(.*?)\_\_/,
  /(\#\#)(.*?)\#\#/,
  /(\-\-)(.*?)\-\-/
]
```

The match any marker regex would look like this:

```
/\?\?.*?\?\?|\_\_.*?\_\_|\#\#.*?\#\#|\-\-.*?\-\-/
```

that is effectively the same regex, just without the matching groups.

Comment: I will note that you cannot nest markers of the same type. e.g. `??test__thing??nest!??__??` but I cant see why anyone would?